# Video Capturing Face Detection- Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera, face-detection

In order to track/detect face during a video capturing. I have reached been able to capture and stored a video. Now I am adding face detection in it. I am now on detecting face during video capture. **How can I check that the facedetect is even working. What changes can i make**:

```
public class AndroidVideoCaptureExample extends Activity {
private Camera mCamera;
private int vWidth, vHeight;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
private Button capture, switchCamera;
private Context myContext;
private LinearLayout cameraPreview;
private boolean cameraFront = false;
private int desiredwidth = 640, desiredheight = 360;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    myContext = this;
    initialize();
}

private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
    int cameraId = -1;
    // Search for the front facing camera
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
        CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
        if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            cameraId = i;
            cameraFront = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return cameraId;
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!hasCamera(myContext)) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Sorry, your phone does not have a camera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        finish();
    }
    if (mCamera == null) {
        // if the front facing camera does not exist
        if (findFrontFacingCamera() < 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            switchCamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        mCamera = Camera.open(findFrontFacingCamera());
        mCamera.setFaceDetectionListener(new FaceDetectionListener());
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
        startFaceDetection();
    }
}

public void initialize() {
    cameraPreview = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

    mPreview = new CameraPreview(myContext, mCamera);
    cameraPreview.addView(mPreview);

    capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    capture.setOnClickListener(captrureListener);

}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // when on Pause, release camera in order to be used from other
    // applications
    releaseCamera();
}

private boolean hasCamera(Context context) {
    // check if the device has camera
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

boolean recording = false;
OnClickListener captrureListener = new OnClickListener() {@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (recording) {
            // stop recording and release camera
            mediaRecorder.stop(); // stop the recording
            releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
            Toast.makeText(AndroidVideoCaptureExample.this, "Video captured!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Toast.makeText(AndroidVideoCaptureExample.this, vWidth + "BY" + vHeight, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            recording = false;
        } else {
            if (!prepareMediaRecorder()) {
                Toast.makeText(AndroidVideoCaptureExample.this, "Failed in prepareMediaRecorder()!\n - Ended -", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
            // work on UiThread for better performance
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // If there are stories, add them to the table

                    try {
                        mediaRecorder.start();

                    } catch (final Exception ex) {
                        // Log.i("---","Exception in thread");
                    }
                }
            });

            recording = true;
        }
    }
};

private void releaseMediaRecorder() {
    if (mediaRecorder != null) {
        mediaRecorder.reset(); // clear recorder configuration
        mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
        mediaRecorder = null;
        mCamera.lock(); // lock camera for later use
    }
}

private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {

    List < Camera.Size > videosizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedVideoSizes();
    Camera.Size videosize = videosizes.get(1);
    //Camera.Size optimalPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(previewsizes, desiredwidth, desiredheight);
    Camera.Size optimalVideoSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(videosize, desiredwidth, desiredheight);
    vWidth = optimalVideoSize.width; //mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width;
    vHeight = optimalVideoSize.height; //mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height;

    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mCamera.unlock();
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    //startFaceDetection();
    //mPreview.setPreviewSize(optimalPreviewSize.width, optimalPreviewSize.height);
    //mCamera.unlock();
    //mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    //mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
    //mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(optimalVideoSize.width, optimalVideoSize.height);
    //myCamera.setParameters(p);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(optimalVideoSize.width, optimalVideoSize.height);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(600000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(50000000); // Set max file size 50M

    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}

private void releaseCamera() {
    // stop and release camera
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(Camera.Size sizes, int w, int h) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.2;
    double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
    if (sizes == null) return null;

    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    int targetHeight = h;

    // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
    Camera.Size size = sizes;

    Log.d("Camera", "Checking size " + size.width + "w " + size.height + "h");
    double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
    if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) <= ASPECT_TOLERANCE) if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
        optimalSize = size;
        minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
    }

    // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the
    // requirement
    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }

    }
    return optimalSize;
}


public void startFaceDetection() {
    // Try starting Face Detection
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

    // start face detection only *after* preview has started
    if (params.getMaxNumDetectedFaces() > 0) {
        // camera supports face detection, so can start it:
        mCamera.startFaceDetection();
    }
}
```

Here is face detection listener class:

```
public class FaceDetectionListener implements Camera.FaceDetectionListener {

@Override
public void onFaceDetection(Camera.Face[] faces, Camera c)
{
    if (faces.length > 0){
    Log.d("FaceDetection", "face detected: " + faces.length +
            " Face 1 Location X: " + faces[0].rect.centerX() +
            "Y: " + faces[0].rect.centerY());

    }
}
```

}

Comment: That API seems deprecated since API Level 21 if I googled that right.

Comment: Okay leaving the video capturing code as it is. How can i achieve face detection part.

Comment: FaceDetectionListener can be used with video capture (see [Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) class). And it is supported by a limited set of devices because it depends on the hardware. For software face detection or from local files you have to use an external library like [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html)

Comment: Hi! I am working on same.. i used your code but could not manage to captured face detected video.

Comment: logcat or anything ? i cant tell u the reason without it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I used Mobile Vision API for Face Detection From Live video, you can Search Mobile Vision API for face detection, it will work Fine,
  but I do not have any method to capture that Detected face and save this detected face in Gallery from live video

Comment: I am sorry for  late reply..,   Please visit this link for understanding Mobile Vision API ,  http://arjunu.com/2015/08/face-detection-with-android-vision-api/

Comment: i think site you gave is of no use